# C# ping program gives strange output

Tags: c#, ping

I have a program which in the future will automatically ping my companys important machines in certain intervals. It gets gets the pingable addresses from a database which for testing purposes now only holds 3 addresses: localhost 127.0.0.1, facebook 66.220.153.15 and google 173.194.67.104.

The problem is that while I'm connected to the internet the program doesnt work and gives mystic output.

The output while not connected to internet

```
127.0.0.1 ping status: Success
173.194.67.104 ping status: HardwareError
66.220.153.15 ping status: HardwareError
Error IP 66.220.153.15
Address: 127.0.0.1 RTT: 0 TTTL: 128 Don't fragment: True Buffer size: 32
Error IP 173.194.67.104
```

and while connected

```
120.1.21.0 ping status: 2406264
Error IP 120.1.21.0
127.0.0.1 ping status: Success
120.1.21.0 ping status: 2406264
Error IP 120.1.21.0
Address: 127.0.0.1 RTT: 0 TTTL: 128 Don't fragment: True Buffer size: 32
```

I have no idea where that strange ip and status come from.

Any help would be much appreciated!

My code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;

static int Main(string[] args)
{
        testidbDataSetTableAdapters.testitauluTableAdapter adapter = new testidbDataSetTableAdapters.testitauluTableAdapter();
        testidbDataSet.testitauluDataTable table = null;
        table = adapter.GetData();

        if (table != null)
        {
            if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    Pinger pinger = new Pinger(table[i].id, table[i].ip);
                    new Thread(new ThreadStart(pinger.Pingaa)).Start();
                }
                Thread.Sleep(2500);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public class Pinger
    {
        int x;
        string Ip;
        public Pinger(int x, string Ip)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.Ip = Ip;
        }

        public void Pingaa()
        {
            AutoResetEvent waiter = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            Ping pingSender = new Ping();
            PingOptions pingOptions = new PingOptions(64,true);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[32];
            pingOptions.DontFragment = true;
            pingOptions.Ttl = 15;
            int timeOut = 2000;
            pingSender.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(pingSender_PingCompleted);
            pingSender.SendAsync(Ip, timeOut, bytes, pingOptions, waiter);
        }
        private static void pingSender_PingCompleted(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ping canceled.");
                ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
            }
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ping failed");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Error.ToString());
                ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
            }
            PingReply reply = e.Reply;
            DisplayReply(reply);
            ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
        }

        private static void DisplayReply(PingReply reply)
        {
            if (reply == null)
                return;

            Console.WriteLine("{0} ping status: {1}", reply.Address, reply.Status.ToString());
            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Address: {0} RTT: {1} TTTL: {2} Don't fragment: {3} Buffer size: {4}", reply.Address, reply.RoundtripTime, reply.Options.Ttl, reply.Options.DontFragment, reply.Buffer.Length);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error IP " + reply.Address);

            }
    }
```

**EDIT**: The strange ip stays always the same but the strange status always changes to a random(?) 7-8 digit number.

Comment: Try pinging to only one address and NOT local host.

Comment: Pinging outside addresses (eg. google.com) gives the same strange output, but when pinging an address of a server in the room next to mine gives right output.

Comment: Does your organization have a proxy?

Comment: Were behind a proxy yes, but with normal commandline ping i can ping google normally and i can trace google with commandline and with an application i've made.

Comment: If your proxy requires authentication? If 120.1.21.0 is the proxy?

Comment: This problem seems to accure even if I'm connected to the internet in home. So it's not a proxy thing. And the 120.1.21.0 points to an address in china when pinged in companys network.